# Why can I invoke asJava once I added import import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

Tags: scala, methods

It looks quite strange to me. I didn't understand how it works. Consider the following example:

```
val m = Map("s" -> "s")
val jm : java.util.Map[String, String] = m.asJava // error
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val jm : java.util.Map[String, String] = m.asJava //fine
```

the method `asJava` is actually defined in `scala.collection.convert.Decorators::AsJava[A](op: => A)`. How can we invoke it on the `Scala`'s `Map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [implicit conversion](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions) going on here. If you look at [the code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConverters.scala#L1), you can see:

```
implicit def mapAsJavaMapConverter[A, B](m : Map[A, B]): AsJava[ju.Map[A, B]] =
    new AsJava(mapAsJavaMap(m))
```

so the compiler is wrapping your `Map` via the above, and the above will provide the `asJava()` method